# Debugging/Referncing Strong Named Libraries

Tags: debugging, release, strongname

How do you correctly setup a solution (C#) that has:

- Web App Project - contains 16 references to other projects/DLLs
- A total of 20 projects outside of the web project
- All projects are Strong Named (pfx file + version, etc)

When I dropped the DLL from references and added a Project Reference instead I am getting Strong Name clashes.

For instance:

When I run with project references I get:
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Company.Handlers.ClientObject, Version=0.9.3457.28069, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=00a0384aefbcb34d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

Line 48:     
Line 49:     
Line 50:       
Line 51:     
Line 52:

I know there must be a way to work in the IDE and ignore strong naming.  Then, with an automated build process, add the strong naming at that point.  Please tell me there is a sane way of doing this...

PS:  The GAC is not involved in any way with these projects.  These are all local copies in the BIN directory upon deployment.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up completely re-architecting the application.  Please vote to close this question as it is no longer relevant.